# How to get Spotify access token using Web API Node

Tags: node.js, api, npm, authorization, spotify

I referred to the link https://www.npmjs.com/package/spotify-web-api-node

Code sample:

```
var SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');

// credentials are optional
 var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
 clientId: 'fcecfc72172e4cd267473117a17cbd4d',
 clientSecret: 'a6338157c9bb5ac9c71924cb2940e1a7',
 redirectUri: 'http://www.example.com/callback'
});
```

In this how can I get the access token?

Answer (score 1):

The specific code above will not return an access token. You'll need to refer to the ["Authorization" section of that package](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node#authorization) where you can decide between the Authorization code flow or the Client Credential flow. Both will return an access token but, depending on your use case, you will have to decide which is the best one for you.

For Authorization code flow it looks something like this:

```
spotifyApi.authorizationCodeGrant(code).then(
  function(data) {
    console.log('The token expires in ' + data.body['expires_in']);
    console.log('The access token is ' + data.body['access_token']);
    console.log('The refresh token is ' + data.body['refresh_token']);
    ...more code
}
```

For the Client Credential flow it looks similar like this:

```
spotifyApi.clientCredentialsGrant().then(
  function(data) {
    console.log('The access token expires in ' + data.body['expires_in']);
    console.log('The access token is ' + data.body['access_token']);
    ...more code
})
```

The [Spotify Guide on Authorization](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/) would be a good resource to help make the decision of which path to follow.